# Integer Sets Intersection

Tags: java, arrays, object, set

The following is a program that creates Integer Sets, I believe I have everything working, except my intersectionWith function is not working correctly.

Here is my IntSet code:

```
public class IntSet{
    private final int MAXALLOWEDSETVALUE=2000;
    private boolean [] data = new boolean[MAXALLOWEDSETVALUE+1];

    public IntSet(int... elts) {
        for(int iteration = 0; iteration < elts.length; iteration++) {
            if(elts[iteration] <= MAXALLOWEDSETVALUE)
            data[elts[iteration]] = true;
        }
    }

    public IntSet(IntSet source){
        System.arraycopy(source.data, 0, this.data, 0, MAXALLOWEDSETVALUE);
    }
    public void setTo(IntSet source){
        System.arraycopy(source.data, 0, this.data, 0, MAXALLOWEDSETVALUE);
    }        

    public IntSet intersectionWith(IntSet other) {
        IntSet newSectionSet = new IntSet(this);
        for(int iteration = 0; iteration < MAXALLOWEDSETVALUE; iteration++) {
            if(newSectionSet.data[iteration] == true && other.data[iteration] == true) {
                newSectionSet.data[iteration] = true;
            }
        }
        return newSectionSet;
    }
}
```

And my Program code:

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Random;
public class Program {

    public static void main(String [] args){
        Random rng = new Random();
        rng.setSeed(0);
        IntSet is1, is2, is3, is4;
        is1 = new IntSet(2,4,5);
        is2 = new IntSet(1,2,5);
        is3 = new IntSet();
        is4 = new IntSet(is2);

        is3.setTo(is1.intersectionWith(is2));
        System.out.print("is3 (intersection): ");
        System.out.println(is3.toString()); // should be 2 5
    }
}
```

Everything seems to be working for me except my intersectionWith function.

This is what is outputted when I run my code:

```
is3 (intersection): {2, 4, 5, }
```

But what it needs to be is just {2, 5}

I am uncertain as how to how I am getting this error.

My intersectionWith function is supposed to create a new set based off of two sets. It only adds an element to the new set if that element is present in both of the two sets.

Comment: This is way too much code to expect people to go through for you. You need to debug to narrow the problem down.

Comment: I'm sorry I actually should just remove most of the code as it is irrelevant

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but 2 comments: 1. What is `newSectionSet.toString();` supposed to do? You make a string version of the set then thrown it away. 2. You should almost never write `== true`; it's redundant in 99.9% of cases. The purpose of `if` is to check if its condition is true.

Comment: I just reduced a massive amount of my code. Sorry for the confusion everyone. And I also added an improved question at the bottom, I'm just a little confused on the logic of finding the intersection between two sets as I guess I'm not understanding it

Comment: according to the above code `is1` does not have any elements

Comment: yes I know wombat. I at first included all of the code but people complained that it was too much code so I took it down. I guess I could put it back up haha.

Comment: @Coder117 [Please add a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Coder117 Did you tried to use `BitSet` and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#and-java.util.BitSet-?

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone but I figured it out myself and posted and answer. I'm really sorry no one liked/understood the question and am sorry for all the confusion.

Comment: @Coder117 now you totally modified your question, please don't do it! if you have a new question post it separately. In this case you want to modify your `toString()`, before the line `output += "}";` add the line: `output = output.substring(0,output.length()-1);` which will remove the extra comma.

Comment: Thank you again! I was going to post another question as I didn't want to erase the history of this one, but I can only post a question every 90 minutes and I didn't want to wait. Also the original question got many downvotes so I guess no harm haha.

Comment: No worries, I rolled back the change otherwise the comments and answers wouldn't make any sense. I also edited it a bit to make it clearer (the example was off since `is1` was declared as an empty set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post only the relevant code and add comments where I added changes:

```
class IntSet{

    private final int MAXALLOWEDSETVALUE = 5; // modified it to a smaller number - easier to debug
    private boolean [] data = new boolean[MAXALLOWEDSETVALUE+1];

    public static void main(String [] args){
        Random rng = new Random();
        rng.setSeed(0);
        IntSet is1, is2, is3;
        is1 = new IntSet(1,2,3);
        is2 = new IntSet(1,2,5);
        is3 = is1.intersectionWith(is2); // I modified the test cases
        System.out.println(is1); // [false, true, true, true, false, false, false]
        System.out.println(is2); // [false, true, true, false, false, true, false]
        System.out.println(is3); // [false, true, true, false, false, false, false]
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() { // added a toString method for a nicer printing
        return Arrays.toString(data);
    }

    public IntSet(int... elts) {
        for(int iteration = 0; iteration < elts.length; iteration++) {
            if(elts[iteration] <= MAXALLOWEDSETVALUE)
                data[elts[iteration]] = true;
        }
    }

    public IntSet intersectionWith(IntSet other) {
        IntSet newSectionSet = new IntSet(); // instead of copying and modifying the copy - just create an "empty" set and update it
        for(int iteration = 0; iteration < MAXALLOWEDSETVALUE; iteration++) {
            if(data[iteration] && other.data[iteration]) { // now the comparison is done directly against `data`
                newSectionSet.data[iteration] = true;
            }
        }
        return newSectionSet;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I already figured out what was going wrong, and I posted my own answer. However I'm going to edit my original question, do you think you could take a look at it? Thank you so much!

Comment: Sure thing! and indeed you found the bug: since you used a "copy" but modified only the places where both the copy and "other" had `true` - places where only the copy had `true` but other had `false` where not modified. That's why I wrote that a clear way would be to *not* use a copy and modify it but rather create a new empty IntSet and use it

Comment: Thank you! I like your way much better.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry Folks looks like I figured it out. I just needed to add an else statement:

```
 public IntSet intersectionWith(IntSet other) {
        IntSet newSectionSet = new IntSet(this);
        for(int iteration = 0; iteration < MAXALLOWEDSETVALUE; iteration++) {
            if(newSectionSet.data[iteration] == true && other.data[iteration] == true) {
                newSectionSet.data[iteration] = true;
            } else {
               newSectionSet.data[iteration] = false; // added this
            }
        }
        return newSectionSet;
    }
```

Comment: That's an option, but there are cleaner ways to do it.